# Is there a way to prevent undefined javascript variables from displaying 'undefined' when inserted into html?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, undefined

I am appending text which is stored in a javascript variable into a div element. The issue is that the depending on the situation there may or may not be text stored in that variable. If there is not I end up with the text 'undefined' where the valid text would have been in the div.

so as an example:

```
htmlelement.innerhtml = '<h2>'+array.object.title+
                        '</h2><p>'+array.object.textField1+
                        '</p><p>'+array.object.textField2+
                        '</p><p>'+array.object.textfield3+'</p>';
```

This shows up in a function which will run for each object in the array. Not all of the objects have content in all 3 text fields.

So is there an easy way to prevent 'undefined from being printed?

Right now I have this before the previous line:

```
if (!array.object.textfield1) {
    array.object.textfield1 = ' ';
}
if (!array.object.textfield2) {
    array.object.textfield2 = ' ';
}
if (!array.object.textfield3) {
    array.object.textfield3 = ' ';
}
```

But this is not a practical solution if there are a lot of variables that need to be checked.

Comment: just initialize the variable with an empty string when declaring it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can you use the [logical operator `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) ?

```
array.object.textField1||''
```

**Note:** Please do take care of values like `0` or any other `falsy` values .

Comment: only issue is if `array.object.textField1 == 0` or some falsy value. OP can just take a note of this.

Comment: This is good alternative if I was to continue checking each variable individually. But If I had a large amount to check this would get very bulky. Or does the logic operator work within the innerhtml method? I'll give it a try, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use "The New Idiot" answer this is here just fro an extra method.

The other answer is better because it molds the check into the logic ( a good thing!) and is better for performance.

with that said **REGEX**!!

```
htmlelement.innerText = htmlelement.innerText.replace('undefined', '');
```

Comment: Nice, I don't know why I didn't think of regex. I'll give this a try.

Comment: I would strongly suggest using the @The New Idiot method. IT's what I would have used and answered. This is here for completeness

Answer (score 1):

check each array item to see if its undefined with the **typeof** operator.
for each array item if the **typeof** is **undefined** you can do eather 2 things:

1. set to default
2. remove with splice()

example:

```
    function cleanArray(theArray){
        for(i=0;i < theArray.length;i++){
            if(typeof theArray[i] == "undefined"){
                theArray[i]="";//OR SPLICE IT OU WITH splice()
            }
        }
    }
    //NOW CALL THIS FUNCTION EVERYTIME PASSING IT THE ARRAY
    cleanArray(arrayOfItems);
```

no simple way around this, you need to plan your design accordingly

Answer (score 0):

"The New Idiot" answer is pretty good if you only have a few.  If you have a more complicated object that you want to sort out, one option would be to iterate over the properties and set them to an empty string if they are undefined. e.g.

```
var o = {
    t1: undefined,
    t2: "hey"
};

for (prop in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof o[prop] === "undefined") {
        o[prop] = "";
    }
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ca6xn/